# Kendo UI Grid Edit popup's change update method return values

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

the normal way in kendo ui grid update data is add a edit popup.
What I want is, Think I change a value in text field.In update I added switch case and change the submit value. Then It will add that value and return that values to the grid. But I want to do is when get the return value and change it and show a different value in the grid.

Here is a example.....

In edit popup it has a input text field. I submit a value as "A". In the update I add a switch tells that If the value is "A" change the submit value to 1(number one).
Then it submit the value and show the value in grid as "1" not as the "A".
How I do this ???

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a custom handler. In the grid you toss in this:

```
edit: function(e) {onEdit(e)},
```

and then on top of the page you do whatever logic you want to do

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (true) {
        $("#Whatever").text('Hello')  //Whatever in this case is a field in grid
```